# How to convert an eloquent query into an array

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following eloquent query which uses a many-to-many relationship to grab all groups associated with the authenticated user.

```
$usergr = Auth::User()->usergroup()->get();
```

Pivot table

```
ID|user_id|group_id
1 |1      |2
2 |1      |3
```

I would like to convert this to an array of `group_id`. So fare it is a collection object however I need this converted to an array to be used on another query.

I have this so far:

```
  foreach ($usergr as $obj)
     {
         $array[]= (array) $obj;
     }
```

The query I for teh array is below:

```
$usergrsub = DB::table('group_subjectlist')->whereIn('group_id', $array)
                                      ->select('subjectlist_id')
                                      ->distinct()->get();
```

However the query above is not recognising the `$array` variable

(I use version 4.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, the [`lists()`](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_lists) function may do what you want.

```
Auth::User()->usergroup()->lists('group_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

Most result objects returned by Laravel's builders have a `toArray()` method that will convert the object into an array.

The `whereIn` method expects an array of values, but the result of `get()` will be a collection of objects, which if converted to an array will be an array of associative arrays.

If you need the `get()` result only for the `whereIn` query you should use `lists('group_id')` instead of `get()`. Otherwise consider using `pluck('group_id')`.

Comment: Thanks but the `toArray()` method does not seem to work.

Comment: @Billy Show us how you used it, and what error you got.

Comment: @Billy updated the answer to match the updated question.

Comment: Thanks to both ceejayoz and nCrazed. I get it now!